# Ámbito variable de clase en función

Tags: php, clase

¿Por qué esta función no tiene acceso a la variable aún siendo `public`?

¿Qué le faltaría para poder ser accedida?

El ejemplo me da error por estar la variable indefinida en la función.

```
<?php
class MiClase {
    public $foo = 5;    

    public function miFuncion(){                    
        echo $foo;  
    }
}

$nueva=new MiClase();
$nueva->miFuncion();
```

Answer (score 2):

Debes utilizar el operador this para hacer referencia a las propiedades de la clase.

```
echo $this->foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Se puede acceder a las propiedades de una clase (dependiendo de su visibilidad) usando el operador `->` para las propiedades no estáticas (sin `$`) y `::` para las estáticas (manteniendo el `$`), anteponiendo `$this` a las primeras y `self` a las segundas en el caso de referirse a las suyas propias:

```
<?php
class MiClase
{
  public $foo = 5;
  public static $bar = 8;

  public function miFuncion()
  {
    echo $this->foo . ' - ' . self::$bar;
  }
}

$nueva = new MiClase();
$nueva->miFuncion();
```

Tienes más información en el siguiente enlace: [propiedades de clase](http://php.net/oop5.properties)

Comment: No esta funcionando como decís. Da un error en la linea:
echo $this->$foo . ' - ' . $self::$bar;
Dice el error:
Notice: Undefined variable: foo in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test2.php on line 9

Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs\new\test2.php on line 9

¿Por que podria fallar?

Comment: Pérdón, fallo mio, en las propiedades no se usa $ cuando se accede a ellas con el operador -> y self mismo no lleva `$. Perdona, programé de memoria :(

Comment: La explicacion es valida pero creo que no funciona por ser una variable de clase desde la que no se tiene acceso desde la funcion.
He probado sin $ pero tampoco me funciona ¿hice algo mal?Gracias

<?php
class MiClase {
 public $foo = 5; 
 
 public function miFuncion(){     
  echo this->foo;  
 }
}

$nueva=new MiClase();
$nueva->miFuncion();

Comment: Todo depende de la visibilidad. Entre clases diferentes se puede aunque sea privada mediante la herencia, y entre clases diferentes se puede si es pública.

Comment: En este caso `$this` mantiene el `$`, mira mi ejemplo corregido.

Comment: Ah si! Gracias. Era eso.